# Best way to use in-memory SQLite for concurrent reads?

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, concurrency

My use case is the following: I have a not-so-big SQLite database, and I want to provide the fastest performance for reading this database concurrently. My database is rarely updated (batch writes once per day), and mostly is queried. What is the best possible set of SQLite pragmas and architecture decisions I can make to achieve the maximum performance?

Specifically, I want to use in-memory SQLite because it's blazing fast. But then, I can't easily read it concurrently. If I use a single connection to an in-memory database, all reads are serialized, and I can't read concurrently. But if I use a pool of connections, I need to initialize database from scratch on each new connection.

Using the file-backed SQLite database allows querying concurrently with lower latency, but all queries are generally slower because the DB is not stored in memory.

What is the fastest way to have an in-memory SQLite database optimized for concurrent reads?

Comment: You can't have an in-memory database used by multiple processes, but you can have multiple connections in the same process use the same one in shared-cache mode. If that's not enough, look for a different database.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for your comment! But I don't have multiple processes. I have a single process with multiple threads. Also, even in the shared-cache mode, all reads are serialized, according to my experiments. IIUC, shared mode is optimized for low memory usage, not for concurrent access. Maybe you have some options and flags in mind I can try?

Comment: Have you tried copying the file-backed database to a RAMdrive (e.g. tmpfs) filesystem and running from there? You could do that after the batch write update.